# Possible to Get ID in NewForm before Saving

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have some sub lists that depend on the ID of an item. I am able to retrieve this in Display and Edit forms because it already exists, but is it possible to get the ID of an item in the New Form before pressing save so I can pass this along to the sub lists?

I would prefer to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: no you can't data needs to be saved in order to generate id. But probably what you can do is, you generate a unique number and set in one feild and use this to pass down to sub lists.

Comment: What about passing the ID of the new form to the display form on save?

Comment: nope you can't, you wont know the id at all unless it is submitted. Also somehow you are able to redirect to somepage how will you know which was the item you created. you can go for last generated but in multiple people submitting form it will fail.

Comment: You cannot vote on your own post 
0

 



I have it working by conditionally redirecting users once they are returned to the All Items page. Basically, once the default SharePoint save and return to items view is complete, I use the REST API to look for the most recently created item by the current author that does not have it's workflow complete and then redirect to the display form.

Answer (score -3):

Let us say that you could and you press cancel. What will happen? You will have a gap on ID's. Is this acceptable to you?